# Running a batch file from the Windows command line

Tags: windows

What command do I use from the command line in Windows Vista to run a batch file called `myBatch.bat`?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to navigate to the batch file, you can e.g. put your batch file in the root of your harddrive (c:)

If you put it here, you can navigate to the root by typing into the command line:

```
c:\
```

Now you can run the batch file by typing

```
mybatch.bat
```

Remember that it is a period before .bat and not a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Just write in cmd line mybatch.bat

Answer (score 1):

Just write the Exact location of your batch file or jump to this location with the terminal:

1. you can use `cd` to move from a directory to another
2. use `dir` to see content of the current directory

then when you are in the file's directory, just type hisname.bat